# Remplazar un archivo de una carpeta y renombrar el archivo

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin

Se esta ejecutando este código, se busca reemplazar un archivo que se guardó en una carpeta usando php. Lo que se busca es poder remplazar el archivo por otro asignándole el mismo nombre, pero con ese código cuando se hace el primer remplazo, lo que hace es crear una nuevo archivo con una parte del nombre y crea un nuevo registro en la tabla, lo que es un error. No se como corregir el problema.

```php
<?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['Modificar'])) {
        $Id_registro = $_POST['Id_registro'];
        
        // Realiza una consulta para obtener el Nombre_documento de la tabla documentos_contrato
        $sql_documento = "SELECT Nombre_documento FROM documentos_contrato WHERE Id = '$Id_registro'";
        $resultado_documento = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_documento);
        
        if ($resultado_documento && mysqli_num_rows($resultado_documento) > 0) {
            $registro_documento = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_documento);
            $nombre_documento_actual = $registro_documento['Nombre_documento'];
            
            // Ruta de destino del archivo
            $rutaDestino = '../Intranet/archivostemporales/';
            
            // Verificar si la carpeta existe, si no, crearla
            if (!file_exists($rutaDestino)) {
                mkdir($rutaDestino, 0777, true);
            }
            
            // Eliminar el archivo existente con el mismo nombre en la carpeta
            if (file_exists($rutaDestino . $nombre_documento_actual)) {
                unlink($rutaDestino . $nombre_documento_actual);
                //echo "El archivo existente fue eliminado: $nombre_documento_actual<br>";
            }
    
            if (!empty($_FILES['archivo']['name'])) {
                $nombre_original = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                $extension = pathinfo($nombre_original, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
                $extensiones_permitidas = array('pdf');
                $maxFileSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4 megabytes en bytes
    
                if ($_FILES['archivo']['size'] <= $maxFileSize) {
                    $archivo_destino = $rutaDestino . $nombre_documento_actual;
                    //echo "Nombre del nuevo archivo: $nombre_documento_actual<br>";
    
                    // Verificar si la extensión del archivo está permitida
                    if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $extensiones_permitidas)) {
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $archivo_destino)) {
                            // Archivo cargado exitosamente, ahora actualizar la información en la base de datos
                            $fechaModi = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $usuarioModi = isset($_SESSION['Username']) ? $_SESSION['Username'] : '';
    
                            // Actualizar los campos Fecha_modificacion, Usuario_modificacion y Ruta_temporal en la tabla documentos_contrato
                            $query = "UPDATE documentos_contrato SET Fecha_modificacion = '$fechaModi', Usuario_modificacion = '$usuarioModi', Ruta_temporal = '$archivo_destino' WHERE Id = '$Id_registro'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    
                            if ($result) {
                                $mensaje_exito = "El archivo se ha actualizado correctamente en la base de datos.";
                                //echo "Actualización exitosa en la base de datos.<br>";
                                // Aquí puedes hacer alguna acción adicional si es necesario.
                            } else {
                                $mensaje_error = "Error al actualizar el archivo en la base de datos.";
                                //echo "Error al actualizar el archivo en la base de datos.<br>";
                            }
                        } else {
                            $mensaje_error = "Error al cargar el archivo.";
                            //echo "Error al cargar el archivo.<br>";
                            // Eliminar el archivo creado si la carga falla
                            unlink($archivo_destino);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $mensaje_error = "La extensión del archivo no está permitida.";
                        //echo "La extensión del archivo no está permitida.<br>";
                    }
                } else {
                    $mensaje_error = "El tamaño del archivo excede el límite permitido.";
                    //echo "El tamaño del archivo excede el límite permitido.<br>";
                }
            } else {
                $mensaje_error = "No se encontró el archivo para cargar.";
                //echo "No se encontró el archivo para cargar.<br>";
            }
        } else {
            $mensaje_error = "No se encontró el registro en la tabla 'documentos_contrato' o el Nombre_documento está vacío.";
            //echo "No se encontró el registro en la tabla 'documentos_contrato' o el Nombre_documento está vacío.<br>";
            // Puedes hacer alguna acción adicional en caso de que no se encuentre el registro.
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SO. Aquí podemos ayudarte con tus problemas de programación. Para conseguir las mejores respuestas, sigue las directrices básicas que el propio sistema te indica:  Resume el problema,  Incluye detalles sobre tu objetivo,   Describe los resultados esperados y obtenidos,  Incluye cualquier mensaje de error, Describe lo que has intentado, Muestra algo de código (en la forma más resumida posible, NO INCLUYAS TODO TU PROGRAMA, tan sólo las instrucciones relevantes a tu problema)

Comment: alguna idea de por que ocurre el error? que has intentado para resolverlo?